# How to pass multi dimensional array as a parameter to function in java

Tags: java

Hey I am new to programming and I have a question how do I pass a multidimensional array as a parameter. I marked it with the ??? signs in code. Thanks in advance

```
package tablicezad2;

import java.util.Random;


public class TabliceZad2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Tablica[][] = new int[2][2];
        wypelnijTablice(???,5,15);  
    }
    int[][] wypelnijTablice(int[][]args,int min, int max){
        int tablica1[][] = args; 
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int tab = rnd.nextInt(max-min)+min;
        int values[][] = new int[3][4];
        for(int i = 0; i<args.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<args.length; j++){
                tablica1[i][j] = tab;  
            }
        }
        return tablica1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The same way you would pass anything else. Why do you have any doubts about it?

Answer (score 1):

you would pass a multidimensional array the same as a normal variable so in your code it would look like this:

```
package tablicezad2;

import java.util.Random;


public class TabliceZad2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Tablica[][] = new int[2][2];
        wypelnijTablice(Tablica,5,15);  //just put the variable referance/name
    }
    int[][] wypelnijTablice(int[][]args,int min, int max){
        int tablica1[][] = args; 
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int tab = rnd.nextInt(max-min)+min;
        int values[][] = new int[3][4];
        for(int i = 0; i<args.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<args.length; j++){
                tablica1[i][j] = tab;  
            }
        }
        return tablica1;
    }
}
```